# If I have a Windows Azure site that doesn't get any hits, am I still charged for the website usage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm not sure how the pricing of Windows Azure websites works. Lets say I create a website and no one visits it. Am I charged the time.

Then lets say that the total time the server spends computing pages and such during the month is 30 minutes. Do I only pay for 30 minutes or do I pay for the entire month the site was available on their servers?

Comment: This really isn't a good stackexchange question; you can't get an authoritative answer here, and even if the one you get is right, Microsoft can CHANGE that answer so it's not useful in the long run.

Comment: @mjfgates - while this might not fit at StackOverflow since it's not specifically a programming question, there's absolutely an authoritative answer. And if Microsoft changes its billing method, dozens (or hundreds) of answers are invalid. Same goes with any other cloud provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Azure compute has always been based on hourly billing (analogous to a hotel room: You pay for the night, even if you're not in the room, using 0% of it).

With Windows Azure Web Sites, *shared instances* are currently free while in preview. If that's what you're currently using, you don't have to worry about being charged. Beyond the 90-day free trial, you'll get an additional 12 months for your shared-instance websites.

Once you go with *reserved instances* then you're paying  for those reserved resources, by the hour. Pricing is similar to Windows Azure Web and Worker Roles (where your application is pushed to Windows 2008 Server virtual machines), except that during the preview, the per-hour pricing is discounted 33%. Detailed pricing breakdown is [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#web-sites).

As others have mentioned, there are other services that will be charged (such as databases, Windows Azure blob/table/queue storage, service bus, bandwidth and others). The free trial includes some bandwidth, database, and storage for free in addition to 10 free shared-instance websites.

Comment: You might want to check out this [interview with Nir Mashkowski](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski), the Program Manager Lead of Windows Azure Web Sites. He clarifies the point that if inactive your Windows Azure Web Site will get removed from memory and effectively set to a 'cold' state. You are not charged CPU time while your site is not in a hot state. which is how 5hr's of free time, can last a 24 hour period

Answer (score 3):

They have an option to "Run up to 10 Web Sites for free in a multitenant environment" during the preview, so if you use that you will not pay for the site itself.  If you use a VM, you will pay per hour, regardless.

There are also other time-based components, like storage, and other optional components that charge by transaction or request count (CDN, Active Directory, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pricing depends on how many hours your website (i.e. role) is up, not how many hours it is *used*.

You can try their [free-trial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) to see how they calculate "compute-hours" under the billing section.

The best is still to contact Azure support as they alone can provide authoritative answers.